# Parsing HTML in android using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to parse HTML into android using Jsoup. When I'm trying to connect to url, I get error

```
Document doc = null;  
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Errors:

```
12-08 13:27:11.254 28041-28041/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
12-08 13:27:11.284 28041-28041/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.krzych.taksometr, PID: 28041
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.krzych.taksometr/com.example.krzych.taksometr.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class selector
```

XML Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.krzych.taksometr.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tekst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your main activity xml code as well as your whole MainActivity java code?

Comment: This error doesn't say anything about Jsoup. It is related to your xml code.

Comment: i think your problem is in **android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable** tag in XML please post your xml file here

Comment: this is not a jsoup error

Comment: There is an xml file. I'm not using  android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable

Answer (score 1):

this works for me :

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JsoupParser().execute();

        }

    });
}
public class JsoupParser extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {
    String title;
    String s = editText.getText().toString();//get url from EditText 
    Document doc;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        textView.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(s).get();
            title = doc.title();

            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        textView.setText(title);
    }
```